# Can we use a calculation when creating an Oracle SQL table?

Tags: oracle

When creating an Oracle SQL table, can we give a calculation? For example

```
create table test (
item-code number,
qty number,
rate number,
(qty*rate)value number
)
```

Comment: Use virtual column concept

Answer (score 1):

use virtual column concept in oracle for more [https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1](http://refer.)

```
create table test (
        item-code number,
        qty number,
        rate number,
        value as (qty*rate)
        )
        /
    insert into testee(item_code,qty,rate) values(1,2,1)
    /
    select * from testee
```

Results

```
ITEM_CODE QTY RATE VALUE
    1     2   1     2
```